# How to delete 'Mark Sharp' edge properties?

Tags: modeling, uv

I have a model which I've given some sharp edges using the **'Mark Sharp'** function.

Now I want to edit the model and remove all the properties of these edges.
I want to keep the edges. I only need the **'Mark Sharp'** to be removed.
*(note: I don't care about losing the UV-mapping data')*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you used Mark Sharp function, then you probably noticed Clean Sharp just below it. Select the edges and use it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>>Clean Sharp).

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved.
One thing though:
I mostly use the spacebar for quick acces to certain functions.
I noticed this option did not display in the quick search, however it did when I entered the CTRL + E shortcut. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I don't use quick search very often and I have no idea why, although it's an interesting observation.I don't see any obvious, logic reason.